# Creating Bulk users in Hybrid model - Exchange 2016

Tags: exchange-2016

I can create the account by this script

```
$CSVLocation = "C:\temp\RemoteUserMailboxes.csv"
Import-CSV $CSVLocation | ForEach-Object {
New-RemoteMailbox -Name $_.Name -FirstName $_.FirstName -Initials $_.Initials -Lastname $_.LastName -OnPremisesOrganizationalUnit $_.OU -UserPrincipalName $_.UPN -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString $_.password -AsPlainText -Force) -ResetPasswordOnNextLogon:$true }
```

To add the properties to the user  i try this script to run on exchange management shell. but throws the error

> The operation couldn't be performed because object 'venky' couldn't be
>   found on 'dc1.ittechsolution.com'

```
$Contacts = Import-CSV -path "C:\temp\RemoteUserMailboxes.csv"
$contacts | ForEach {Set-contact $_.Name -StreetAddress $_.StreetAddress -City $_.City -StateorProvince $_.StateorProvince -PostalCode $_.PostalCode -Phone $_.Phone -MobilePhone $_.MobilePhone -Pager $_.Pager -HomePhone $_.HomePhone -Company $_.Company -Title $_.Title -OtherTelephone $_.OtherTelephone -Department $_.Department -Fax $_.Fax -Initials $_.Initials -Notes $_.Notes -Office $_.Office }
```

why does this error occurs?

Comment: How about run "Get-Contact venky" to view contact settings first?
If you create it by New-RemoteMailbox, it should be a remote mailbox instead of contact. Thus, run "Get-RemoteMailbox venky" to check.

If so, we need run the script with Set-RemoteMailbox.

Comment: Get-Contact -identity venky  The operation couldn't be performed because object 'venky' couldn't be found on 'dc1.ittechsolution.com'   if only command Get-contact given it list of users but could not find venky in it.